# Что лучше: сразу вставлять в отсортированном порядке, или отсортировать массив потом?

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, математика

Я вот думаю как лучше оптимизировать приложение, чтоб быстрее работало. Нашел место в коде, хорошо годящееся для оптимизации. Там заполняется массив в 150-200 (рандомно от 150 до 200) элементов, без каких-либо сортировок. То есть и поиск постоянно линейный (это игра, в игре 60 раз в секунду проверяется этот массив).

Соответственно я не знаю, что будет лучше: сначала не учитывая порядок добавлять элементы в массив, а потом уже отсортировать с помощью эффективных алгоритмов сортировок, либо же изначально добавлять, учитывая порядок?

Дело в том, что алгоритм добавления, учитывая порядок, аналогичен сортировке вставками (Insertion Sort), временная сложность которого О(n^2), в то время как сложность алгоритма "вставить и потом отсортировать" будет n + (n * log(n)). n для того чтобы заполнить массив и n log n для того, чтобы отсортировать.

Так вот действительно ли будет на практике решение "заполнить и потом уже отсортировать" более эффективным?

Что вообще из этих двух вариантов будет наиболее эффективным в моем случае? Что мне стоит сделать?

Comment: "в игре 60 раз в секунду проверяется этот массив" - проверяется или заполняется?

Comment: При инициализации игры массив заполняется. Потом уже в процессе игры координаты игрока сверяются с координатами бомб в массиве. То есть каждую секунду 60 раз линейно проходится этот массив.

Comment: Вариант третий - не сортировать - не рассматривался? Созданный массив обрабатывать без сортировки "с помощью эффективных алгоритмов". Вдруг получится быстрее?

Comment: ну и как вы будете быстро искать элемент в неотсортированном массиве? Линейным поиском? Это я уже пробовал, а теперь хочу оптимизировать.

Comment: Если массив не меняется, то эта оптимизация не имеет значения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, объясните более подробно, что Вы имеете ввиду. 
Мне надо понять, находится ли элемент с определенными координатами в массиве. Быстрее это сделать можно с помощью бинарного поиска. Так как элементов 150-200, а проверяется наличие этого элемента 60 раз в секунду, то я думаю что это вполне полезная оптимизация - вместо линейного (200 итераций) использовать бинарный (log2(200) = 7 итераций) поиск. Теперь осталось решить, как будет быстрее совершить инициализацию. Я нагуглил и нашел, что вставками в определеном порядке будет 22500 итераций, когда в ином случае их будет ~1234.

Comment: Иной случай - это вставить и потом отсортировать. Хочу чтобы вы прокомментировали вышесказанное.

Comment: Что значит "проверяется массив"? Может эффективнее будет хэшированная, а не сортированная структура.

Comment: Проверяется наличие элемента в массиве.

Comment: Во время игры еще 3-4 элемента могут быть удалены из массива.

Comment: Стоит написать и один, и второй варианты и посмотреть время работы. Ибо *Практика - критерий истины. (с) Маркс* :) Это единственный реально работающий способ...

Comment: Max итераций по сравнению в несортированном - 200. Min итераций сортировки  + max  итераций поиска в сортированном - 1234+7... Но количество - вещь относительная. При таких цифрах время итерации сравнения должно быть больше времени итерации сортировки в 6-7 раз. Только практика покажет оптимальное решение.

Comment: @Harry ещё на практике стоит рассмотреть другие алгоритмы, которые без сортировки работают или реже её требуют.

Comment: Ребят, о каких алгоритмах идет речь, если массив неотсортирован? Есть только 2 алгоритма поиска: линейный и бинарный (да-да, я знаю что есть еще разные навороченные алгоритмы типа поиска интерполяции, но они не всегда эффективны и на практике используются только эти два). Что вы еще предлагаете кроме линейного поиска для поиска в неотсортированном массиве?

Comment: Вам же уже подсказали, что кроме массивов, есть и другие структуры данных, специально придуманные для эффективного поиска. Кроме того, задачу `координаты игрока сверяются с координатами бомб в массиве` можно решать и другими способами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше сперва вставить все необходимые данные, а потом уже сортировать, так как каждый раз запускать сортировку накладно, так как при таком подходе каждый раз Вам придется пытаться отсортировать массив (что уже потребует линейного времени на проверку каждого элемента).

Comment: Да, это уже давно понял и так сделал, Вы правы!

Comment: Вставлять каждый раз в отсортированном порядке это больше походит на Insertion Sort. То есть временная сложность будет O(n^2). 
Когда воспользовавшись встроенной сортировкой сложность будет O(n log n).

Comment: Не совсем. Вставка элемента, это вставка элемента (да, она присутствует в сортировке вставками, но не более). Сортировка это сортировка. Если вы будете вставлять элемент и каждый раз запускать сортировку, то у вас каждый раз будет уходить квадрат от количества элементов. Если вы будете каждый раз вставлять элемент, у вас будет уходить линия от количества элементов.

Comment: Ну так я это и имею ввиду. Если 100 элементов вставлять в отсортированном порядке, уйдет O(n^2) = ~100000 итераций.
А вот если я все вставлю и отсортирую то будет 100 + 100 * 6 = 700 итераций.

Comment: O(n^2) = ~10000 * *